# Feynman diagram of $\Xi^{-}$ decay

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, quarks

How would one go about drawing the Feynman diagram for the following reaction?

$$\Xi^{-} \rightarrow n\space+\pi^{-}$$

In terms of quarks:

$$dss\rightarrow udd\space + d\overline{u} $$

Could the reaction be mediated by two $W^{\pm}$ bosons similar to the $K^{0}\rightarrow \overline{K^{0}}$ reaction?  In the $\Xi^{-}$ case, could the $s$ quarks change into two $d$ quarks while one of them also emits a gluon which gives the $u\overline{u}$ quarks ?

[image]

Image from B.R. Martin's Nuclear and Particle Physics Ch.6 - Electroweak reactions - page 202.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this must be a doubly weak decay, as you can see from the BR in PDG, and *must* involve two virtual *W*s to eliminate two *s* quarks.
The basic reaction is
$$s\rightarrow u W^{-} \to u    d \overline{u}, $$
and you need two of those.

So,  overall
$$
dss \to   d ~~ u    d \overline{u} ~~ u    d \overline{u}\leadsto udd+ d\overline{u},
$$
with a $\overline{u} u$ pair annihilating to a gluon you attach anywhere you like.